# opening an hiddevice failes

Tags: hid, udev

I have a device to program which uses `hidapi`. I had problems in opening a device when running my program in eclipse. My first guess was that it is a permission problem.

So I added the following `udev` rule in a text file, with vendor and product id of my device:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="06cb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="009a", MODE="0666"
```

in the /etc/udev/rules.d

I rebooted the system and plugged in the device again.
Now when I try

```
sudo udevadm test /dev/usb/hiddev3
```

(which is the path to my device), I can see in the list that it reads the rule I added. But still I get this message at the end:

> unable to open device '/sys/dev/usb/hiddev3'

So my question is:

- Is it really a permission issue that hinders access to the device? If not, what are other problems that can block opening a hid device?
- If it is a permission issue, how can I solve it? Is there any other `udev` rule to add?

I am on `ubuntu 18.04`.

Thank you very much